# How to deal with "weird" phase plots in bode diagram when designing a controller

Tags: matlab, nyquist, control-systems, bode, pid

I am trying to design a balance controller for a robot. With MATLAB simulink I arrived at the transfer function between the input and the pitch angle for the robot. I have plotted the bode and Nyquist plot below.

[image]

As you can see, the Nyquist plot looks very weird, and in the bode diagram the signals at low frequencies are attenuated. To fix this, I added a zero at the peak of the magnitude plot, so
$$\omega_i=10 \text{rad}/s \Rightarrow \tau_i = \frac{1}{\omega_i}=0.1\text{s}$$

This results in an I-term which looks like this: $C_i(s)= \frac{\tau_is+1}{\tau_is}=\frac{0.1s+1}{0.1s}$

When I add this to the controller the bode plot now becomes.

[image]

Now I also want to add a lead-term to prevent overshoots but the way I usually do that is to change the crossover frequency $\omega_c$ such that there is good phase margin, define some constant $\alpha$, and then find the lead term with the formula $\tau_d = \frac{1}{\omega_c \sqrt{\alpha}}$. Then I can make my lead-term with
$$C_d = \frac{\tau_d s + 1}{\alpha \tau_d s + 1} $$

But when I look at the current phase plot, it all around looks like there is no trouble regarding the phase margin. The phase is never close to $-180^{\circ}$ so I am not sure how to proceed with such a weird looking phase plot.

So my question is, how do I find my lead-term when the phase plot looks like this? Is there another way to do than I have proposed?

### Edit

The open loop transfer function between the input and pitch angle is $G(s) = \frac{ 5.893e05 s^4 + 7.71e08 s^3 + 1.435e11 s^2 + 2.566e12 s + 7.683e09}{s^7 + 2418 s^6 + 1.317e06 s^5 + 1.977e08 s^4 + 1.312e10 s^3 + 1.796e11 s^2 - 9.658e11 s - 1.525e13}$
Using the "pole" command in MATLAB I noticed that there was a pole in the RHP which should cause some instability.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to assess the stability of the open-loop plant? your high frequent behaviour looks like -60dB/dec, indicating 3 dominant poles. However, the phaseshift from +90 to -90 shows only 2 dominant poles. This can indicate the presence of an unstable pole

Comment: @Petrus1904 I have made an edit to the question. I am not quite sure what you mean with your first question, but as you can see in the edit there actually is a pole in the right half plane which would cause instability. The pole $0.0087 +0i$ is unstable, right?

Comment: I suspect you might have pole/zero cancellations in your transfer function, 

Maybe you should work with zpk instead of tf.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit puzzled with your Bode plot, here's what I get with your transfer function and Matlab 2019b. My phase starts at almost -180 degrees while yours start at 0 degree. Is it possible that you've made a mistake somewhere in your analysis?

[image]

Your transfer function is a bit complex, you could simplify it by removing the fast poles and zeroes. For example, you have 2 fast poles at -1714 and -516 and a fast zero at -1088. You can remove the 2 fast poles and the fast zero to simplify your transfer function. This will make your analysis easier.

Secondly, I think the rule-of-thumb formulae you use for the cross-over frequency is only valid when your open loop system has a low-pass characteristic. Your system has a band-pass characteristic.

Comment: The system he describes is flipped, the actual system is $-G(s)$.

Answer (score 1):

Following your edit, the first challenge in creating a controller is the task to create a stabilizing controller. After that, performance can be tuned. In order to find if the created controller stabilizes the closed-loop, the nyquist plot can be used. The nyquist stability criterion states that the amount of encirclements of the point -1 (hereby are counter-clockwise encirclements negative) are equal to $N = P-Z$. $P$ represents the amount of RHP poles of the open loop system and $Z$ the amount of RHP poles of the closed loop system. Therefore, in order to stabilize the closed-loop knowing that $P = 1$, the amount of encirclements of the nyquist contour should be 1 (which implies that $Z=0$). To be sure, this means 1 clock-wise encirclement, or one more clock-wise encirclement that counter clock-wise encirclements.

Achieving stability can be as easy as using just the right feedback gain. a root locus plot might indicate that `rlocus(sys)`. However, I went tested that myself, just a gain is not going to achieve it. In this case, it could even be an unstable controller is able to stabilize the system. Sadly, I cannot provide direct rule of thumbs that ensure stability. After the closed loop is stabilized, I am pretty certain the bode plot will have a proper phase and gain margin (as it practically must cross the -180 phase angle).

Happy tinkering!